# C# Reading of text file stopped working - with Unity

Tags: c#, text, unity-game-engine, text-files

I have a program that reads in any amount of .txt files in a directory and assembles them in a list, this list is then displayed to the user one at a time. The user makes a decision at this point and the reaction time is stored. Recently the text import script stopped working for no reason. I haven't changed any of the text import code in months.

I've checked the code that reads in the files and nothing was being recognised at all.

This is part of Unity program just FYI.

TextImport

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TextImport : MonoBehaviour {

    public static List<string> TextLines;
    bool FileRead = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake() {
        TextLines = new List<string>();
        string path;
        if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor)
        {
            path = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/";
        }
        else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer)
        {
            path = Application.dataPath;
        }
        else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
        {
            FileRead = true;
            path = "/StroopTest/";
            TextAsset Allfiles = Resources.Load("Android/AllText") as TextAsset;
            string[] AllLinesAndroid = Allfiles.text.Split("\n"[0]);
            foreach (string Line in AllLinesAndroid)
            {
                TextLines.Add(Line);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            path = Application.dataPath;
        }
        if (!FileRead)
        {
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] fileInfo = info.GetFiles("*.txt");//I've changed the "*.txt" to nothing to read all files instead of just .txt files
            foreach (FileInfo file in fileInfo)
            {
                //I created another List here to store the file names that were read, however none were.
                string[] AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);
                foreach (string line in AllLines)
                {
                    TextLines.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on which platform are you running it when it fails? is the failure an exception, or does it just idle? any chance that you could debug it and inspect values at runtime?

Comment: It's only when running it through the windows player, if I run it in editor it works fine

Comment: Is using `Application.persistentDataPath` not an option?

Comment: Consider adding the runtime value of `Application.dataPath` to `TextLines` temporarily for debugging purposes, to see whether it really points to the directory where you have your files.

Comment: @andeart it is an option, I'll give it a go

Comment: @dlatikay I've done this and it is definitely pointing to the right folder

Comment: @andeart using `Application.persistentDataPath` returns a location in the AppData folder but does work. Why doesn't `Application.DataPath` then?

Comment: you should only ever use, and you must use, Application.persistentDataPath.  Never use any other location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `Application.persistentDataPath`.

`Application.dataPath` is a read-only directory, where (if packaged to do so) you can find game-related assets there.

`Application.persistentDataPath`, however, is a writeable directory and returns a path (different for different platforms) where you can add stuff at runtime (ex: writing a file, downloading a file, etc.)

I hope that helps.