# File read/write paradigms on Unity- which to use?

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, io

I want to load some JSON files that are stored in my assets.

I don't know where I'm supposed to store them in the assets. Should I store it in the "Resources" folder, in the "StreamingAssets" folder or somewhere else ?

I don't know what path I'm supposed to use. I heard you need to write : `path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/";` for the StreamingAssets but there is also `Application.streamingAssetsPath`. I also heard you always need to use `Application.persistantDataPath`. So which path should I use ?

I don't know what I can use in to access the files in C#. I've heard you can use Directory.Exists() and File.Exists() but if you use the StreamingAssets you must use WWW. Is that right?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35488234/5095609). I hope that's helpful! :)

Comment: In addition, I would suggest placing anything you want to package with your game in your Resources folder, which you can access by using [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). If you want to write files, they *have* to go in Application.persistentDataPath as that's the only writeable directory (that's specified by Unity). You can of course specify absolute paths but that's more risk than necessary (device paths differ).

Comment: If I use the Resources folder, can I iterate through the directories and files ? If I understood well, persistentDataPath is used for runtime files so I can't use it for assets that are not generated during runtime ? So I guess I should use Application.dataPath, but where should I store files so I can find them in dataPath ? And which class should I use to check if a file/directory exists ?

Comment: Yes, you can iterate through directories however you want- ex: `Resources.Load("folder/file");`.
Yes, persistentDataPath is only for runtime files, *but* once a file is stored there, it is persistent between sessions.
You could ignore `Application.dataPath` altogether, until you find a specific need for it (accessing other game files that are not in pDP, but not in resources either). Why do you need to find them from dataPath specifically?

Comment: I hope you don't mind continuing this on my answer post. I feel like this is gradually answering your question, even though it originally started as a suggestion comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a basic idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487529/c-sharp-reading-of-text-file-stopped-working-with-unity/35488234#35488234).

In addition, I would suggest placing anything you want to package with your game in your Resources folder, which you can access by using [Resources.Load()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). You can iterate through these directories however you want- ex: `Resources.Load("folder/file");`.

If you want to write files, they have to go in `Application.persistentDataPath` as that's the only write-able directory (that's specified by Unity), i.e. for run-time files only. But once a file is stored there, it is persistent between sessions.

You can, of course, specify absolute paths and try to load assets from there, but that's more risk than necessary (paths differ on different devices).
You could ignore Application.dataPath altogether, until you find a specific need for it (ex: to access files that are not in persistentDataPath, but not in resources either).

I hope that helps!

Comment: Then I must use Resources because my files must be stored during the build and not during the runtime. But how do you check if a folder exists with Resources ?

Comment: Hmm, there is a way, but to simplify things, would `if (Resources.Load("folder/file") != null)` be enough to solve your problem?

Comment: The *way*, as I mentioned above, is `if (Directory.Exists("Assets/Resources/folder1"))`. But you shouldn't feel the need for it in most cases, as `Resources.Load` either returns the asset or null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I just tried `if (Directory.Exists("Assets/Resources/folder1"))`. It works in the Unity Editor but it doesn't work in Android. I know a way to do it without checking if the folder exists but it would be really annoying.

Comment: Oops. Try `if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources/folder1")))`. I hope that works.

Comment: Hmm, that bit might need a little debugging. I forget the exact way (or if there even is a way to do it).

Comment: It also doesn't work, but I guess you can't do it on Android... I will try to do it with Resources.Load. But the problem is that I don't want to load them, I just want to check if they exist because they are thousands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104467/discussion-between-andeart-and-servietsky).